# MVC 3 ninject bind lazy evaluated parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I want o bind my controller with a parameter that is lazy evaluated.

```
 protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        try
        {
            return controllerType == null
                       ? null
                       : (IController) _ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And I have the next binding:

```
_ninjectKernel.Bind<IFilesRepository>().To<FilesManager>().WithConstructorArgument("storageFolderAbsolutePath", c => c.ToString());
```

The problem is at the lambda function. I want to return Server.MapPath("/") ... but I don't have the request context in the c object. How can I sent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with Ninject, but you should be able to register a provider with the container to be able to resolve a `HttpContextBase`. By doing so, the `IFilesRepository` can now take a `HttpContextBase` as a constructor argument, which will be injected by the container, using the provider, when creating an instance of `IFilesRepository`.

To register a provider (using a delegate to resolve the service),

```
Bind<HttpContextBase>().ToMethod(context => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

Be aware however, that the life style of an `IFilesRepository` would most likely need to change to a "per Web Request" lifestyle, as the `HttpContext.Current` is created per web request, so you wouldn't want to go holding onto that in an `IFilesRepository` that had a longer life style. You may want to abstract out the "mapping paths" functionality so that you can have an `IFilesRepository` with a longer lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

Since the server variable is related to the current HttpContext you will have to retrieve it inside the FilesManager class (using a separate Interface for that purpose if you will )